# Unsure about a maths symbol

Tags: matrices, notation

Help, help, help!

I've come across this maths symbol,

$[n(i,j)]^{0.5}$ where $n$ is a square matrix.

Does this mean that it is the $(i,j)$ element of $n^{0.5}$? or $n(i,j)^{0.5}$?

source: http://outobox.cs.umn.edu/Random_Walks_Collaborative_Recommendation_Fouss.pdf

2nd page, fifth line from the top of left column:

> [image]

Thanks a million in advance!

Eh... after looking at some notation he used at page 367, my guess is element-wise square-root?

Comment: Don't edit someone's formatting if the question is specifically asking about clarification on notation/symbols. @ClementC.

Comment: @DanielRust he edited the OP's post to match the article he was referencing

Comment: What does this have to do with matrices and roots?

Comment: May be it stands for $\sqrt{\sum{n^2_{ij}}}$.

Comment: I upvoted this because, unlike many similar questions, it contained a clear pointer to the source of the notation. Thanks!

Comment: If $A$ is a symmetric and positive semi-definite matrix then there exists a $B$ such that $A=B^tDB$, where $D$ is diagonal. Some people like to call $B=\sqrt A$. I am not sure about the context but, it may be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see where it is defined explicitly.  It looks like the square root of the $(i,j)$ element of $n$, as opposed to the $(i,j)$ element of the square root of $n$.  I say that because he justifies that the elements are positive and therefore have square roots, but doesn't seem to remark that the matrix will have a square root.  It will, but I would have expected it to be mentioned if needed.

Comment: then i remembered about mathematica, link:
-->[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=[n%28i%2Cj%29]^0.5]<--
, i guess that's the case, element-wise square-root, thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Section 5.1. (on page 5) has the following formula:

$$n(i,j) = V_G (x'_i - x'_j)^T (x'_i - x'_j) = V_G \| x'_i - x'_j \|^2,$$

so I'd say that $[n(i,j)]^{1/2}$ stands for an ordinary element-wise square root, i.e.,

$$[n(i,j)]^{1/2} = \sqrt{n(i,j)} = \| x'_i - x'_j \|\sqrt{V_G}.$$

Value $V_G$ is defined in section 4.2 as the *volume of the graph* $V_G = \sum_{k=1}^n d_{kk}$, i.e., a nonnegative number, so it has a square root.